# In ExtJS, what is the difference between features and plugins?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have been trying to find a simple explanation for the difference between a feature and a plugin. They both seem to add some additional functionality to a component, but what is sets them apart? When would you create one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A feature is a type of plugin that's specific to the grid panels.

[Feature Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Feature)

Answer (score 2):

Both provide extra functionality.

A feature is something that alters the markup of the grid in some way

- Grouping
- Row body

A plugin fits into any other category.

Comment: RowExpander is a plugin :)

Comment: It wraps the row body feature, so it does indirectly modify the markup.